# android get date of milliseconds

Tags: android, calendar

i have a future date in milliseconds and i would like to convert it to a "Calendar Instance" like this:

```
long FutureDateinMilliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis() + 68435123141;

Calendar calToday = Calendar.getInstance();
calToday.set(Calendar.YEAR, YEAR VALUE OF FutureDateinMilliSeconds );
calToday.set(Calendar.MONTH, MONTH VALUE OF FutureDateinMilliSeconds);
calToday.set(Calendar.DATE, DAY VALUE OF FutureDateinMilliSeconds);
calToday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calToday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calToday.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calToday.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

i hope you understand my question and many thanks for your help.

Comment: what is 68435123141 ?

Comment: this is a millisecond example. current + this example is the future date in milliseconds

Comment: First set the time of your calendar to FutureDateinMilliSeconds (, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_settimeinmillis.htm)  then set minute, second, etc. to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to do to get the date as a Date Object in android

```
  long FutureDateinMilliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis() + 68435123141l;
    Date fDate = new Date(FutureDateinMilliSeconds );
```

If you want the date in particular format you can use

```
String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cDate);
```

Comment: thank you, this works !. but another question. is this line in my code correct for setting the Day?  calToday.set(Calendar.DATE, msCal.get(msCal.DAY_OF_MONTH));   is Calendar.Date correct for Day?

Comment: For Day It would be Calender.DAY_OF_MONTH in the beginning.the rest seeems to be correct

Answer (score 2):

Please use this method as per requiriment,

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
    {
        // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

        // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date. 
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
         return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
    }
```